# How set a identification to Canvas Path?

Tags: html, canvas, path, html5-canvas, identification

Good morning everyone.

I'm building a graph for the enterprise system where I work, but I came across a problem where I need to insert some kind of identification, that I may be rescued by **JavaScript** (*name, id, label, ...*).

Someone could tell me how I could do to identify each element of the graph separately? To be more exact, what I'm wondering identifies each element ***arc*** is created.

---

If someone wanted to see the code to understand it better, I'll put the link here:
  - [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/EJoZoFI/2/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you draw on the canvas is automatically remembered or labeled with an id.

All canvas drawings become forgotten and inaccessible pixels.  However there are ways of keeping track of your various drawings.

Instead of keeping your posX,posY and color info in separate parallel arrays, how about creating an object for each node.

Then you could add the id property to each node object:

```
var nodes=[];

nodes.push({id:"sun", x:100, y:100, color:"yellow"});
nodes.push({id:"earth", x:50, y:50, color:"blue"});
nodes.push({id:"moon", x:50, y:60, color:"gray"});
```

And, of course, pull the graphing info from each node...

You can draw your graph inside a function and apply a scaleFactor when needed.

```
    function drawGraph(){
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        context.save();
        context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.length;i++){
            var node=nodes[i];
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(centerCanvasX,centerCanvasY);
            context.lineTo(node.x,node.y);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(node.x,node.y,node.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle=node.color;
            context.fill();
        }
        context.restore();
    }
```

For dragging/clicking/etc, You could hit test each node array element until you found a match.

```
function hit(x,y){
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        var node=nodes[i];
        var dx=node.x-x;
        var dy=node.y-y;
        var rr=node.radius;
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<rr*rr){
            return(i);
        }
    }
    return(-1);
}
```

The matching element would have the id you need.

If your graph is scaled and you're using mouse coordinates to drag, you must adjust the coordinates that the browser gives you by the current scaleFactor of your graph:

```
mouseX=parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX)/scaleFactor;
mouseY=parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY)/scaleFactor;
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/c4hsW/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var centerCanvasX=canvas.width/2;
    var centerCanvasY=canvas.height/2;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;

    var nodes=[];
    var dragNode;

    var scaleFactor=1.00;

    nodes.push({id:"sun", x:centerCanvasX, y:centerCanvasY, radius:20, color:"yellow"});
    nodes.push({id:"earth", x:50, y:50, radius:5, color:"blue"});
    nodes.push({id:"moon", x:50, y:65, radius:3, color:"gray"});

    drawGraph();

    function drawGraph(){
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        context.save();
        context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.length;i++){
            var node=nodes[i];
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(centerCanvasX,centerCanvasY);
            context.lineTo(node.x,node.y);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(node.x,node.y,node.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle=node.color;
            context.fill();
        }
        context.restore();
    }

    function hit(x,y){
        for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
            var node=nodes[i];
            var dx=node.x-x;
            var dy=node.y-y;
            var rr=node.radius;
            if(dx*dx+dy*dy<rr*rr){
                return(i);
            }
        }
        return(-1);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX)/scaleFactor;
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY)/scaleFactor;

        var i=hit(mouseX,mouseY);
        if(i>=0){ 
            startX=mouseX;
            startY=mouseY;
            isDown=true;
            dragNode=nodes[i];
        }
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
        if(!isDown){return;}

        // get the current mouse position
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX)/scaleFactor;
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY)/scaleFactor;
        // reposition the dragged node
        dragNode.x+=(mouseX-startX);
        dragNode.y+=(mouseY-startY);
        startX=mouseX;
        startY=mouseY;
        // redraw the graph
        drawGraph();
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

    $("#bigger").click(function(){
        scaleFactor+=0.20;
        drawGraph();
    });

    $("#smaller").click(function(){
        scaleFactor-=0.20;
        drawGraph();
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="bigger">Scale Up</button>
    <button id="smaller">Scale Down</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I adapted your example to work in my code, but I ended up creating another problem.
What I need is a way to "call" these nodes of an external place, without having to recreate the whole graph.

Comment: Happy to help...Could you explain "call these nodes externally"?

Comment: The code I presented is a summary of what I have. There are other functions that are not there, with a scaling accompanying the user window. The problem is that when the user resizes the window, just created another chart above. And that's a problem.

I need to separate the "criaGrafico" the "events.setStage". But in doing so, I lose the animations. So I need an ID to each node, so that it can be called from JavaScript without need to recreate the chart.

Comment: You don't have to adjust much to resize your chart.  Create a scaleFactor variable that you can adjust as the windows resizes.  Then use that scaleFactor when drawing your chart: context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor).  To match mouse coordinates to your scaled graph, you must divide any mouse event coordinates by that scaleFactor: mouseX = event.clientX/scaleFactor.  I have edited my answer to include graph scaling.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: I tried using the "scale", but not served to me. Who determines the zoom level is the user. Not to mention that the scaling is not done from the center. Also, as I said, there are other functions that need an ID as well. =/

Comment: If you want to zoom from the center, just context.translate to the center before context.scale and then adjust the mouse coordinates by the translate.  It's ok if the user is determining the scaleFactor (eg using mousedrag or pinch). When they indicate their desired scale, just set scaleFactor and call drawGraph.  Also, You can draw other shapes besides circles. Just add a "shape" property to the node object and draw the appropriate shape in drawGraph. Canvas is flexible enough to handle your graphing needs. Anyway, you could alternatively use a canvas drawing library or a graphing library.

Comment: The user uses an input[type=range] to determine the level of zoom. And, as I said, this is not the only function that needs identification. There are other function not yet implemented that do not work without this identification.

Comment: One last thought...you might consider SVG instead of canvas.  The SVG drawing capabilities are similar to canvas, but since SVG objects are true html DOM elements, they are persistent (remembered). Since they are persisted, SVG objects can have ids, be manipulated, respond to events, etc.